# layout_below and multiline TextView issue

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I use a RelativeLayout with some TextView one below another and at the end a ViewPager.

the ViewPager have android:layout_below="@id/dialog_access_right" in his parameters , dialog_access_right is the last TextView .

My issue is that this particular TextView CAN (but not necessarily) be multiline (max 3). But the ViewPager is always positioned after the first line so it hide the rest of the TextView.

I tried using multiline, set line parameters to 3 (not too bad if there is two blank line in some cases), put a default text with two newline.
Nothing of this work.

is there a way to tell the ViewPager to redraw and align itself (i tried invalidate on the relativelayout, but nothing...) with the view above ?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_access_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/access_right_title"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/access_right_title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/access_right_title"
    android:text="@string/dialog_access_right" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/dialog_access_right" />
```

edit:here's a screenshot to show my issue, the "Can Read" TextView is in reality a multiline TextView with 2 lines (can be 3), the blue line is a PagerTabStrip inside the ViewPager
[image: screenshot]

Comment: can you post any screenshot of your problem. difficult to assume.

Comment: added one screenshot with explanation

Comment: try in your textview android:minLines="3" or give marginBottom="15dp" for your viewpager.

Comment: i already tried minLines. marginBottom is a workaround (i think , didn't tried it yet) but not really a solution.

Comment: it's the same thing, i suppose it will work but that didn't explain why the base config doesn't work and how to fix it. i'll do it if i don't found anything else but i'd like to avoid this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why (well, how to solve this) this is happening.

it's because of the

```
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/access_right_title"
```

it's seem that this parameters is the culprit.When i remove it (the layout_alignBaseline too) and replace it with another parameter (android:layout_below in this case) the ViewPager is right positioned.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_access_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/last_modified_date_name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/access_right_title"
    android:text="TextView" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/dialog_access_right" />
```

I don't know if this is a bug or something wanted but even if in my case the android:layout_below does the job , it's may not always be...

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting your ViewPager first at the bottom and then putting your textView above it.
You also don't really a separate view for your label. You can just pull a string resource and concatenate it. Not only does this optimize view drawing, it also makes your XML files smaller and easier to understand and debug.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:align_parentBottom="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_access_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:above="@id/viewpager"
    android:below="@id/dateModified"
    android:text="@string/dialog_access_right" />
```

Comment: Just tried it, still the same except that the textview is above of the viewpager (in the z-index) wich is normal.If i don't separate the label, how i can align the three lines, considering that the second line will began at the bottom of the label and not the "Can Read"? (don't know if i'm very clear)

Comment: I think I follow you. It seems that you probably have to call invalidate() on you layout after your call to setText(). That will force everything to get remeasured and drawn. Hopefully that will fix it.

Comment: Humm. Well the last thing I can think of would be to just add a margin to the top or bottom of your views. However, I don't think that is the best fix. It's more of a hack for you given situation. I'll post any more ideas that come to mind. And make sure to post your solution if you figure it out.

Comment: yes , just as i said on the question comment , i don't think that's a solution either even if it works. What i wonder now its if this is a bug or something else. If this is a bug i suppose i should report it...

Comment: i just found out why this is happening , check my answer if you're interested in.